# Error handling with python script in ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0

I have a python script that I am using to create a list of all mxd files (with full pathing) in our Projects folder.  The script then uses that to iterate through the list and do a findandreplaceworkspacepaths on each mxd per ESRI's how to.  I am running into problems when I hit a corrupted mxd file.  The have tried try/except and haven't gotten it to work.  The ideal situation would be to write the corrupt filename to a file and move on so I can come back to them at the end.  I'm very new with python scripting, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import arcpy, os, sys, traceback, time

oldpath = 'W:'
newpath = 'W:\\GIS'

def find(path,pattern):
    matches = []
    for r,d,f in os.walk(path):
        for files in f:
            if files.endswith(pattern):
                fpath = os.path.join(r,files)
                matches.append(fpath)
                print (fpath)
    return matches


print ("Go: ")
mxdlist = (find('C:\\gis','.mxd'))
print (mxdlist)


print ("Starting Path Conversion")
try:
        for mxdold in mxdlist:
            mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdold)
            mxd.findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths(oldpath, newpath)
            time.sleep(6)
            mxd.save()
            time.sleep(6)
            print (mxdold)
            del mxd
    except arcpy.ExecuteError:    
        arcpy.AddError(arcpy.GetMessages(2))    

    except:    
        arcpy.AddError("Non-tool error occurred")
```

Answer (score 7):

First thing to do is bring the top of your `for` loop outside the `try` statement. You want to get into your iteration before you give the `try` statement a chance to kill your operation. Next you'll want to add a few lines to open an error log and write filenames of corrupt files.

```
import arcpy, os, sys, traceback, time

oldpath = 'W:\\'
newpath = 'W:\\GIS'
cgis_dir = 'C:\\gis'

mxdlist = []

print 'Go: '
files = os.listdir(cgis_dir)
for file in files:
    try:
        if file.split('.')[1] == 'mxd':
            mxdlist.append(file)
            print cgis_dir,file
    except:
        pass


print ("Starting Path Conversion")

for mxdold in mxdlist:
    try:
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdold)
        mxd.findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths(oldpath, newpath)
        time.sleep(6)
        mxd.save()
        time.sleep(6)
        print (mxdold)
        del mxd
    except arcpy.ExecuteError:    
        arcpy.AddError(arcpy.GetMessages(2))
        f=open(r'W:\GIS\error.log','a')
        f.write(mxdold,'\n')
        f.close()

    except:    
        arcpy.AddError("Non-tool error occurred")
```

Comment: +1 Nice one, beat me to it! However, don't open the log file with `'w'`(rite) - use `'a'`(ppend) instead as if there's more than one corrupt mxd you'll overwrite each time. Also, it may be overkill, but the Python [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module might be worth looking at to record errors.

Comment: Nice catch... fixed the code to open the file with `'a'` to append.

Comment: It is still failing with the modified code.  I have verified that the files are not corrupt but I get it where Windows 7 claims it to have hung and kills the script.  Any ideas?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Can you post the rest of the code?

Comment: There is no error other than windows just saying that pythonw.exe has stopped working. Edited post above.

Comment: Please note that I've incorporated the extra code you posted in the answer into your original post. I've then altered the code in the answer to provide a more direct way to get your list of mxd's. As for the solution, I don't know that any of this will help yet. Does your code process anything before it is deemed that Python has timed-out or does it just hang from the get-go?

Comment: I have 2 suggestions:

 1. Don't reinvent logging and log files. I've got a little Python logging howto at http://sgillies.net/blog/832/python-logging/ that has other good links.
 2. Consider ditching the call to arcpy.AddError since you're writing your own handler action.

Comment: It is hit or miss as to what it handles.  I've had it run successfully on over 30 files before it hits a file that it won't work on.  As far as I know there is nothing special about the file that it hangs on.  I have a support request in with ESRI but they are not sure why it is doing this either.  The mxd opens fine, but it seems like there is an issue with the findandreplace line.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with your error on the corrupt MXDs, but since you are wanting to log, here is a little bare-bones nugget (pretty much straight from the Python docs) using the `logging` module (as suggested by @om_henners). @sgillies comment above looks excellent as well.

```
import logging
import datetime
import os

date_tag = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")
log_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.curdir), "LogFileTest_%s.log" % date_tag)

# Setup logger
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
                    filename=log_file,
                    filemode='w')
logging.info(': START LOGGING')

try:
    logging.info(": Do something here")
except Exception, err:
    logging.error(": %s" % str(err))
```

When run as-is, it gives:

[image]